# How to force HTML background to bottom when page is smaller than window

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

I have a page with 2 background images, one of them needs to show at the very bottom of the page. Currently I've implemented it like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('/cheri/image/background.png'), 
                      url('/cheri/image/backgroundB.png');
    background-position: top, bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
}
```

This works fine when page content is higher than the browser window, but if it's smaller an empty white space is left below the background image, like in this picture:

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4560/screenshot20120916at851.png

I have tried to set the body as position:absolute, height:100%, but it did not render correctly when scrolling was present. I have also attempted to create a separate div for the background image and absolutely position it to the bottom, but since I have different position properties for some elements that occur at the bottom, the z-indexing didn't work properly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: multipe image in the background-image will create the problem in below Internet Explorer (9.0 )

Comment: Thanks, but I can resolve that. This problem exists regardless if I use 2 background images or 1..

Comment: It looks like you may not have set the background-position correctly, it expects a argument like "top left" for each background.
What you probably should set for background-position is  "0 top, 0 bottom"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100%` on both `html` and `body`:

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3731948/3f3ce1f2f132adf14e8aca4236ee090bcdaff2c8)

It creates no issues when you have enough content to cause scrolling.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3731948/8721b626ef93595980c394dc12e88e699d92b246)

Answer (score 1):

Set the HTML element as well:

```
html {
    background-image: url('/cheri/image/background.png'), url('/cheri/image/backgroundB.png');
    background-position: top, bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
}
```